# JQuery draggable change element on start

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, web

Is it possible to change the element being dragged on the 'start' method? For instance, if I have a button titled 'yellow square' that can be dragged. It just says yellow square, but when you drag it you're actually dragging a yellow square, and not the button with the draggable property.

I suppose I'm asking if it's possible to alter an element that is currently being dragged?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. Have a look at the api-docu: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#visual-feedback

example "customer helper" should be what you're looking for.

This is the relevant code:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    helper: function( event ) {
        return $( "<div class='ui-widget-header'>I'm a custom helper</div>" );
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah man, I read through the whole thing and didn't see it. In my defense, they didn't exactly shout about it. Thanks for pointing it out!